# Renaming a field in an object

Tags: javascript

If I have the following object:

```
JsonObj = {
    "frames": {
        "cinema": {
            "sourceSize": { "w": 256, "h": 200 },
            "frame": { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 256, "h": 192 }
        },
        "tree": {
            "sourceSize": { "w": 128, "h": 110 },
            "frame": { "x": 0, "y": 302, "w": 70, "h": 96 }
        }
    }
};
```

This JSON object is parsed into the variable `parsedJSON` using this JavaScript code:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JsonObj);
```

How would I rename the "frames" property in `parsedJSON` to something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the `somethingElse` as a reference to what `frames` points to, then delete `frames`.

```
parsedJSON.somethingElse = parsedJSON.frames;
delete parsedJSON.frames;
```

The important thing here is that `frames` is simply a pointer to an object; if you delete the `frames` pointer, `somethingElse` still references a valid object.

---

<sup>Also note there's no such thing as a "JSON object"; you have a JSON representation of an object, which is a string, *or* you have an object (which can often be defined via object literal notation, which is often where the confusion lies).</sup>

Comment: Generally, there's such a thing called JSON object
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON. But yes, topicstarter was referring to a serialized string, not the object.