# conditionally change a json property based on a json label - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, label

I have a JSON file which i load into my javascript var

Before plotting my data:

```
{
    "Month": "September",
    "Value": 1681937,
    "Year": 2013
},
{
    "Month": "April",
    "Value": 2138286,
    "Year": 2014
},
```

I need to replace the label "Value" with "Value+Year" which will look something like so: "Value2013" for September and "Value2014" for April.

From StackOverflow I understand this should be doable in javascript but i don't understand how to access for every entry the value of Year and replace the Label Value with Value+Year

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What *exactly* are you having problems with? I assume you know how to iterate over an array? You basically have to combine [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123/218196) with [Renaming a field in an object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14789405/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
var my = [{
    "Month": "September",
    "Value": 1681937,
    "Year": 2013
}, {
    "Month": "April",
    "Value": 2138286,
    "Year": 2014
}];

console.log('my (before) :', my);

for(var i=0; i<my.length; i++) {
    my[i]["Value" + my[i].Year] = my[i].Value;
    delete my[i]["Value"];
}

console.log('my (after) :', my);
```

See the console of the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/Vr7qc/5/) to choose the one you need:

Result will be :

```
[{
    "Month": "September",
    "Value2013": 1681937,
    "Year": 2013
}, {
    "Month": "April",
    "Value2014": 2138286,
    "Year": 2014
}]
```

---

EDIT : You can see the different common possibilites and their performance results here : http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-underscore-each-vs-for-loops/18

Comment: Thank you it works. How can you write JS so fast -.-

Comment: Hello, I mark your as answer, however I ended up using the _ below. The reason I mark your as a valid answer is because doesn't make use of external lib. If anyone feels differently comment below

Comment: Thx. I understand your choice. But according to this specific usage, it is way-faster to use the native javascript  `for..in`. See this jsPerf to understand : http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-underscore-each-vs-for-loops/4. Jquery or Underscore `.each` are really slower than the other solutions. You should never use them  this way.

Comment: By the way, I figured out that `for..in` is not that fast that I tought. It is better to use `for(var i=0; i<my.length; i++)` or even the reverse for ... I updated my post.

Comment: If i save my json in a file say: file.json  can i load it and pass it to your function? I tried: var chartDataSource = $.getJSON( "file.json"); but it doesn't seem to work because the data are stored in some complex object. I tried chartDataSource.array but got nowhere

Comment: Sure. But I you will need to parse it before. (with stuff like `JSON.parse()`).

Comment: This is an other issue. You should post a new question about your `getJSON()` that does not work as expected. Put the content of the file and js-code you're trying to execute...

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to achieve this smoothly.

Given an array of objects

```
var myArray=[{
    "Month": "September",
    "Value": 1681937,
    "Year": 2013
},
{
    "Month": "April",
    "Value": 2138286,
    "Year": 2014
}];
```

Your replacement should be:

```
_.each(myArray,function(element) { 
    element['Value'+element.Year]=element.Value; 
    delete element.Value; 
});
```

Resulting array is

```
[{
    "Month": "September",
    "Value2013": 1681937,
    "Year": 2013
},
{
    "Month": "April",
    "Value2014": 2138286,
    "Year": 2014
}];
```

Comment: Thank you it works more compact but it requires to include underscore.js

Comment: I ended up using this solution very elegant and +1 for _ i never heard of that stuff

Comment: underscore will become your best friend. I never leave home without it.