# Correctly load and parse a JSON file with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I am trying to load and manipulate a JSON file in Javascript however, when i load the json like so:

```
var my = $.getJSON("../file.json");
console.log('my (before) :', my);

for(var i=0; i<my.length; i++) {
    my[i]["Value" + my[i].Year] = my[i].Value;
    delete my[i]["Value"];
}

console.log('my (after) :', my);
```

The JSON is unchanged. The opposite happens when i load JSON like so:

```
var chartDataSource = [
        {
            "Month": "August",
            "Value": 1176124,
            "Year": 2012
        },
        {
            "Month": "December",
            "Value": 1205852,
            "Year": 2012
        }];
```

The for loop correctly performs the changes into the data structure.

[credit for the loop goes to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144323/conditionally-change-a-json-property-based-on-a-json-label-javascript/24144582?noredirect=1#comment37321516_24144582)

Comment: You should try reading the documentation for `getJSON` and pay attention to what its return value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Your `var me` is probably not populated with data. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("../file.json", function(my){
  console.log('my (before) :', my);

  for(var i=0; i<my.length; i++) {
    my[i]["Value" + my[i].Year] = my[i].Value;
    delete my[i]["Value"];
  }

  console.log('my (after) :', my);
});
```

And be sure to check that your server is configured to return the value of `../file.json` as text. Likely F12 in your browser will reveal if the file is served.

Comment: You are correct, i got confused reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file